# pdflatex not working anymore after updating pdflatex.ini and initexmf --dump=pdflatex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, format-files, capacity

I tried to overcome the well known tex capacity exceed problem, when using large Surf-plot with many datapoints.

I tried this by typing into the cmd (Windows 7, MikTex 2.9):

```
initexmf --edit-config-file=pdflatex 

main_memory=5000000 
extra_mem_bot=5000000 
font_mem_size=5000000 
pool_size=5000000 
buf_size=5000000 

**initexmf --dump=pdflatex**
```

Now, pdflatex does not work anymore, a dvi is built, but no output.

The log also says that the system maybe just failed. 
pdflatex is broke... 
Any Ideas? (I cannot think of a proper MWE.)

Comment: Can you skip the dvi and directly compile a PDF? Try with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX run.

Comment: What happens if you use pdflatex directly on the command line with a hello-world.tex?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for me the solution was to delet the content of the .ini-file, and redo the dumping. So just call the first command, delet all the content in the opening editor and then call the last command: initexmf --dump=pdflatex

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!